# Canon rebel t3i settings for pageant

Tags: canon-600d

I am unfamiliar with this camera and will be shooting pictures of my daughter in a high school pageant. What is the best camera settings to use? Not certain if flashes will be allowed, so will need to know setting options for this as well.

Comment: What lenses do you have? Do you have the standard kit lens EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS, or any additional lenses to chose from?

Comment: Ed's 55-250mm and 18-55mm

Answer (score 2):

If you are totally unfamiliar the best thing to do would be to take photos in **no flash mode which is beside the green auto**. If you feel even that is blurry or too grainy then go ahead and use the full auto. In that case the flash would automatically popup.

If you know the camera a bit, **try shooting in aperture priority with the lowest f number** you get (will range from 3.5 to 5.6 on a kit lens depending on how much you are zooming). You might want to increase the f number a little if you are taking group photos or photos of the stage and settings. Keep the ISO around 800 if you don't have good lighting. If the place is well list you can go ahead with ISO200. **The high ISO is to ensure that you get a fast shutter speed in aperture priority so that your photos are sharp.**

And finally if you can lens some lenses I would suggest maybe a 50mm prime or a 85mm prime depending on how far your daughter is going to be. **You will get really nice portraits with blurred backgrounds with a prime lens**. But do rent it a day ahead and try it out.

Hope you are able to take awesome photos :)

Comment: Thank you so very much..big help! I did just learn that there is absolutely no cameras..so, of course I will have to opt for the "no flash" setting!